# Why does $\int_a^b f(x)\, dx = \int_a^c f(x)\, dx + \int_c^b f(x)\, dx$ only hold when $a<c<b$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$\int_a^b f(x)\, dx = \int_a^c f(x)\, dx + \int_c^b f(x)\, dx$; $a<c<b$

---

Why should $c$ lie between $a$ and $b$ when the property perfectly holds *(under some conditions)* even when it doesn't lie between them?

Comment: Even if $c\notin (a,b)$ it sitll hold.

Comment: As long as the antiderivative $F$ is defined on the whole interval $\min\{a,b,c}}, \max\{a,b,c\}$ I see no reason why $a<c<b$ is required.

Comment: Who says that it holds *only* under that condition?

Comment: @GyroGearloose The existence of the antiderivative is irrelevant. The integral is a limit of Riemann sums (or a Lebesgue integral).

Comment: Often we start with $f:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$. then we're only sure these integrals even exist if $c \in [a,b]$.

Comment: @Martin R Wikipedia and many other sites.

Comment: @Cognoscenti Stating something holds for $a<c<b$ does not imply it doesn't hold in more generality. It is just that $a<c<b$ is the usual setting where all the involved integrals are of the kind $\int_x^y$ with $x<y$. Do Wikipedia and many other sites explicitly state it *only* holds for $a<c<b$?

Comment: @Christoph They don't. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is typically used for the case of inbetween $c$ to split functions like $|x-1|$ that have two different formulae depending on the domain. ($1-x$ if $x<1$ and $x-1$ if $x > 1$ so it can make sense to split on $c=1$ when we integrate over a larger interval).

We can *make* it work for all $c$ by adopting "conventions" like $\int_a^a f(x)dx=0$ and $\int_a^b f(x)dx = -\int_b^a f(x)dx$, but sometimes we don't want to talk about such artificialities. Most text books want to compute concrete integrals where we only use the intermediate case, and not study general integration "trickery".

Comment: Why should $\int_a^af(x)dx=0$ be a convention? Isn't this a direct result from the Riemann definition?

Comment: @GyroGearloose Yes, but the negative sign convention is artificial (but justifiable ).

Comment: You're right for functions in ***R***, but for path integrals in ***C*** it comes quite naturally.

Comment: @GyroGearloose true, but then we have a different "kind" of integral. I was (like the OP I suppose) considering the real to real case only.

Comment: Could you please [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3833217/826417) this question too?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this equation is shown early on in the introduction of integrals. For an outside number $c$ you need additional conventions that may be not mentioned in this early stage of introduction.